# Wordpress Plugin - Saving simple data about a post

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin in wordpress that allows you to age restrict certain posts and pages but not others.  I looked for a plugin that does this and couldn't find one.  I've got all the coding covered except I can't figure out how to instruct wordpress to save the state of the checkbox as data associated with that post or page.  I dissected a couple of plugins that have similar functionality but am mystified by how their code works and it breaks when I try to modify it for my use.

Can someone point me to a tutorial that explains how data gets saved from the post edit page and how to access that data later?

Comment: It's best to post what you have tried. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

check out **post meta-data** :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

The basic idea is WP allows you to add additional fields to a post, and then retrieve it during the loop. Just use this field to test against at render-time and display alternate content, should (in this case) your post be restricted.

The codex is pretty thorough on the subject, and I'm sure google can fill in the gaps -

Hope that helps